# How to simulate browser access with plone.app.testing and PAS plugin

Tags: unit-testing, authorization, plone, plone-4.x

I'm developing a PAS plugin for Plone and inside test coverage I'm also testing generated HTML (I'm not using zope.testbrowser or similar, what I need to test is really simple).
The problem is that when test runs be call stack is totally different from browser usage (on a real Plone site I replicated the test environment).

Here a piece of the test that fail:

```
portal = self.layer['portal']
request = self.layer['request']
request.set('ACTUAL_URL', 'http://nohost/plone/folder/subfolder')
request.set('URL', 'http://nohost/plone/folder/subfolder')
login(portal, 'user2')
output = self.folder.subfolder()
```

Up there *subfolder* is an ATCT Folder and I'm calling it's default view (folder listing).

Now, the PAS plugin is implementing the `checkLocalRolesAllowed` method.

```
def checkLocalRolesAllowed(self, user, object, object_roles):
    ...
```

What's is happening:

- using **browser** the first call to `checkLocalRolesAllowed` is done with `object`= <ATFolder at subfolder>, `user`='users2'
- running the **test** the first call to `checkLocalRolesAllowed` is done on the portal root with: `object`= <PloneSite at plone>, `user`='user2'

On both situations the method is called a lot of additional time (which is normal) but the call order is totally different.

In the **test** the *subfolder* context is only the 4rth in the stack order (the Plone site on the first two times, ZCatalog the third).

Starting from the fact that the "good" behavior is the one reproduced by the browser, how can simulate the same behavior on tests? Why calling `portal.folder.subfolder()` is using the Plone site at the first call?

**NB**: I tested other combinations like using `restrictedTraverse`, `portal.folder.subfolder.folder_listing()`, ... nothing worked.

Comment: Did you try using PLONE_ZSERVER layer?

Comment: No (never used it), probably changing layer will fix my issue, I was thinking about switching to PLONE_FUNCTIONAL_TESTING but my question was about keeping tests simple and reproduce the right behavior.

Comment: If you want produce the exactly same behavior in tests, as with a browser, you need to load the hole stack in your test environment. That's why I propose the ZServer layer. I assume the Zserver layer has the same stack as a regular browser request on a running plone installation.